# Access a Caddy server by IP

Tags: docker, docker-compose, caddy, caddyfile

I have a website with **docker** and I use caddy for production. This is my configuration on my `Caddyfile`

```
mydomain.com {
    proxy / django:5000 {
        header_upstream Host {host}
        header_upstream X-Real-IP {remote}
        header_upstream X-Forwarded-Proto {scheme}
        header_upstream X-CSRFToken {~csrftoken}
    }
    log stdout
    errors stdout
    gzip
}
```

**This configuration works well when I use mydomain.com**, but when I try to access the server by IP it returns me the following error:

```
404 Site 156.130.11.8 is not served on this interface
```

I've tried using `*`, `156.130.11.8`, and `:80`

```
* {
    proxy / django:5000...
    ...

156.130.11.8 {
    proxy / django:5000...
    ...
```

None of this is working either, does anyone of you know how can I solve this?

EDIT:
The code is here: https://github.com/maguayo/django-starter-api
Caddy configuration is under **compose/production/caddy/** also the configuration I am running is on "**production.yml**"

Comment: Can you provide sample git repo to see the problem in action?

Comment: @TarunLalwani yes. Here you have it: https://github.com/maguayo/django-starter-api Caddy is under compose/production/caddy and production.yml on the root

Comment: I ran `docker-compose -f production.yml up` and it is given some errors?

Comment: No. There should not be errors using docker-compose -f production.yml up, but trying to access the website through a browser it returns 404 Site 156.130.11.8 is not served on this interface

Comment: Have you defined the `DOMAIN_NAME` environment variable in the `.env` file. It should be `*:80` then only your setup will work

Comment: @TarunLalwani I know, that should work but it doesn't. I can't access the website at all, with the IP or the domain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195126/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-marcos-aguayo).

Comment: My answer probably was way too broad, was it?

Answer (score 6):

According to these tutorials:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-a-website-with-caddy-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://www.booleanworld.com/host-website-caddy-web-server-linux/

https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile-tutorial

your Caddy server should serve the website on your ip using port 80 using one of the follwing configurations:

```
* {
    proxy / django:5000...
    ...

156.130.11.8 {
    proxy / django:5000...
    ...

:80 {
    proxy / django:5000...
    ...

http:// {
    proxy / django:5000...
    ...
```

Maybe `http://156.130.11.8 { proxy / django:5000 ... }` will do the job. Also try to use `localhost` instead of the ip address like this:

```
localhost {
    proxy / django:5000...
    ...
}

http://localhost {
    proxy / django:5000...
    ...
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I already tried that and I am getting the same error: 404 Site 156.130.11.8 is not served on this interface

Comment: is the 404 coming from caddy or django? Have a look at django's logs.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your Django `settings.py` only has the **mydomain.com** as allowed host and not the IP? That way the server should return something like "is not served on this interface" and it shouldn't when the domain name is used.

I experienced a similar problem some time ago, not with Caddy but Apache also on Ubuntu. It would also explain why changing your Caddy config doesn't solve the problem, as it is correct.

`settings.py` should have a line like

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [IP, 'mydomain.com']
```

More on this parameter can be found [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts).

Comment: My settings have ALLOWED_HOSTS=["*"] :(

Comment: Ah, my bad. And you didn't find a solution in  the meantime?

Comment: And in your docker config your have the settings to port forward the ports?

Comment: I am not sure. this is my config: https://github.com/maguayo/django-starter-api/blob/master/production.yml

Probably has to do with docker..

Comment: When you tried to access the IP address, did you specify the port? If you want you can take a deeper look on [docker networking in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/), but as far as I can tell, yours looks pretty solid, as long as someone specifies the port.